# What kind of raid I have?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, raid, storage, software-raid

I have the raid option on bios and I got Intel chipset SATA/PCIe RST premium and  Microsoft Storage Spaces controllers under storage controllers on device manager but both my disks on basic mode. Is it software raid or hardware raid ? I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's neither. You have RST and Storage Spaces enabled, but you're not using them.

You can use RST to create so-called "fake RAID" which is a misleading name, because it's a proper RAID. This type of RAID is neither pure software nor pure hardware RAID - a third type, essentially. See the [discussion in the comments here](https://superuser.com/a/1655194/194694) if you're interested in the details.

Storage Spaces is software RAID.

No matter which one you'll choose, your both drives will eventually appear as a single one. With RST you'll be able to boot from it. With Storage Spaces, the system volume will have to be a basic one. Anyway, it will involve erasing them.